# find the sublist whose first element is the maximum that is no greater than a given number

Tags: python

I have a list of sublists, and the first element of each sublist is a number. I would like to find the sublist whose first element is the maximum that is no greater than a given number. I wonder how to implement that?

For example, I would like to find the sublist in list `a`, so that its first element is the maximum one which is no greater than `3`. The sublist is `[2,'b']`.

```
>>> a=[[5,'d'] ,[1,'a'],[4,'c'],[2,'b'] ]
>>> a = sorted(a)
>>> a
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [4, 'c'], [5, 'd']]
>>> [3>=x for [x,_] in a]
[True, True, False, False]
>>> a[1]
[2, 'b']
```

Thanks and regards!

Comment: How would ties be broken? Or are the first elements guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: yes, unique. @Pradhan

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a=[[5,'d'] ,[1,'a'],[4,'c'],[2,'b'] ]
>>> max(filter(lambda sl: sl[0]<3, a), key=lambda sl: sl[0])
[2, 'b']
```

Break that down:

1) Produce the sub list of the list of lists that meets the criteria of `sl[0]<3` using [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> filter(lambda sl: sl[0]<3, a)
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]
```

1.a) You could use a list comprehension also:

```
>>> [sl for sl in a if sl[0]<3]
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]
```

2) Then find the [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) of that subset list using a key function:

```
>>> max([[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']], key=lambda sl: sl[0])
[2, 'b']
```

3) Combine -- one line -- no sort -- be happy...

Answer (score 1):

```
def grab_max_pair(lst_of_pairs, num):
    result = None
    for pair in lst_of_pairs:
        if result and pair[0] <= num:
            if pair[0] > result[0]:
                result = pair
        elif pair[0] <= 3:
            result = pair
    return result

a=[[5,'d'] ,[1,'a'],[4,'c'],[2,'b'] ]    
print grab_max_pair(a, 3)  # prints [2,b]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension with something like:

```
a = # define your list here
new_list = [list for list in a if list[0] < 4]  # only grab sub-lists that meet your criterion
new_list = sorted(new_list)  # sort them now (shorter list)
result = new_list[0]  # grab the first result
```

You could throw this all into a function if it is something that you do a lot:

```
def get_first(my_list, criterion=4):
    new_list = [list for list in my_list if list[0] < criterion]
    new_list = sorted(new_list)
    return new_list[0] if new_list is not None else None  # avoid a crash if new_list[0] does not have meaning
```

You could then call this (with or without a value for criterion, default is 4) from Python after importing whatever module you have placed it inside, or after defining it in your environment:

```
>> my_list = # define your list here
>> smallest_match = get_first(my_list)
```

Comment: thanks. Is there a simpler way to get the last element of a list, than `mylist[len(mylist)-1]`?

Comment: `return new_list[0]` will crash in case that `new_list` is `None`

Comment: @Tim, the last element can be returned with `my_list[-1]`. Any negative value starts from the last item at `-1` and indexes backwards through the list.

Comment: @alfasin, true, you could use something like `return new_list[0] if new_list[0] is not None else None` to avoid a crash.

Comment: @alfasin, runs fine when I test it. I suppose it should be `if new_list is not None`. Check out [ternary operators](http://www.pythoncentral.io/one-line-if-statement-in-python-ternary-conditional-operator/) in Python or, specifically, [PEP 308](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) for more info.

Comment: @Engineero interesting, maybe something I missed ? https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/25234/577468/e1nJCfwpF0mQ8lZ/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-06%20at%209.18.17%20PM.png

Comment: I think you need the `else ` half of the statement to make it valid. Otherwise it doesn't know what to return if the condition is not met.

Comment: No need to sort: `O(n log(n))` operation

Comment: I thought the point was to get the smallest match, not just the first. You could write your own loop to find and compare matches, but the sort is syntactically simple, which i hope makes for a clearer answer to their question.

Comment: It is not necessary and potentially slow on larger lists. Careful -- people learning to code are watching ;-)